# I am trying to scan a char in my main method and my program just prints and exits

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I am trying to scan and my method just prints and exits. It won't scan.

```
int main() {
    char *one = (char*)malloc(34* sizeof(char));
    char *two = (char*)malloc(16* sizeof(char));
    char test ;
    printf("please enter a Q \n");    
    scanf("%c", test);
    printf("%c\n", test); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", test);` -> `scanf(" %c", &test);`

Comment: Decent compiler should be able to warn you about this mismatch in `scanf` format-string and arguments. If your doesn't try to enable more warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` for GCC and Clang, `/W4` for MSVC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
scanf("%c", test);
```

should be:

```c
scanf("%c", &test);
```